# Accelerator for JButton

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

How do set a shortcut, eg. Ctrl+Q, to a `JButton`? `JMenuItem` has `setAccelerator()` method to set one, but `JButton` doesn't.

Comment: Look at this answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588145/create-hot-keys-for-jbutton-in-java-using-swing

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can do a JMenu with a set og instruction, putting inside them the same ActionPerformed you put in the specified JButton. It's a good trade-off

Comment: Otherwise, you can use the MNemonic function