# create hot keys for JButton in java using swing

Tags: java, swing

I use the following code to create hot keys for the java form using swing. If I press ALT+N,ALT+R,ALT+1,ALT+2 the cursor moves to correct text fields and I enter the value in corresponding Text Fields. It works properly. My problem is, I have Save and exit JButtons in this form if. I press CTRL+S means the Save button will be selected at the same time If i press CTRL+X means the exit button will be selected. How to create mnemonics for JButton? How to do CTRL+S,CTRL+X this using the following code?

Thanks in advance.

```
package hotkeys;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;
public class hotkey extends JFrame {
    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        JLabel Name = new JLabel("Name");
        JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(20);
        Name.setLabelFor(tf1);
        Name.setDisplayedMnemonic('N');


        JLabel Regno = new JLabel("RegNO");
        JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(20);
        Regno.setLabelFor(tf2);
        Regno.setDisplayedMnemonic('R');

        JLabel Mark1 = new JLabel("Mark1");
        JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(20);
        Mark1.setLabelFor(tf3);
        Mark1.setDisplayedMnemonic('1');

        JLabel Mark2 = new JLabel("Mark2");
        JTextField tf4 = new JTextField(20);
        Mark2.setLabelFor(tf4);
        Mark2.setDisplayedMnemonic('2');


        JButton b1 = new JButton("Save");
        JButton b2 = new JButton("eXit");


        JFrame f = new JFrame();
        JPanel p = new JPanel();

        p.add(Name);
        p.add(tf1);
        p.add(Regno);
        p.add(tf2);
        p.add(Mark1);
        p.add(tf3);
        p.add(Mark2);
        p.add(tf4);
        p.add(b1);
        p.add(b2);

        f.add(p);
        f.setVisible(true);
        f.pack();
    }
}
```

Comment: please what do you needed else, without any progress??? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8586353/create-hot-keys-in-java-using-swing, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585544/enter-key-using-in-jtextfield-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8584998/hotkeys-creation-for-java-swing-form,

Answer (score 21):

You need to register a keyBinding in the button's component inputmap. In code (repeating a subtle variant of what you have been told to do in your previous questions :-)

```
// create an Action doing what you want
Action action = new AbstractAction("doSomething") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("triggered the action");
    }

};
// configure the Action with the accelerator (aka: short cut)
action.putValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY, KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("control S"));

// create a button, configured with the Action
JButton toolBarButton = new JButton(action);
// manually register the accelerator in the button's component input map
toolBarButton.getActionMap().put("myAction", action);
toolBarButton.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(
        (KeyStroke) action.getValue(Action.ACCELERATOR_KEY), "myAction");
```

Answer (score 10):

Sun has a really good Description of the whole Key Binding issue. You can find it here:

[JavaSE Tutorial on Keybinding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

**//EDIT**

**Edited my example code so you can just copy + paste it and it will work. Included the points that were missing, thanks for the feedback.**

```
KeyStroke keySave = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, Event.CTRL_MASK); 
Action performSave = new AbstractAction("Save") {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
         //do your save
         System.out.println("save");
    }
}; 
JButton b1 = new JButton(performSave); 
b1.getActionMap().put("performSave", performSave);
b1.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keySave, "performSave"); 

KeyStroke keyExit = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_Y, Event.CTRL_MASK); 
Action performExit = new AbstractAction("Exit") {  
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {     
        //exit
        System.out.println("exit");
    }
}; 
JButton b2 = new JButton(performExit); 
b2.getActionMap().put("performExit", performExit);
b2.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW).put(keyExit, "performExit");
```

Comment: good direction - just a bit incomplete: additionally you need to a) register the actions in the button's actionMap b) if you want a window-scope short-cut, register the keyStroke in the "component inputMap", that is the one of type JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW, instead of the default (which is WHEN_FOCUSED)

Comment: just noticed c) the Action should have its name property set (instead of instantiating the button with a text) - so downvoted for now, will revert once you correct the little issues :-)

Comment: Thanks for your feedback kleopatra. :) I now edited the code samples so it will work after copy + pasting. Have a good day.

Comment: Ok right. Is c) correct aswell now? Because I never worked with those names before. Wow learned something new, sweet :)

Comment: perfect :-) as very last bit of sugar glazing, you might consider to use the getStroke(String) method which is the recommended way of grabbing one - though a matter of taste at the end of a day

Answer (score 1):

Just modified your code. (inserted code in //******)
Just 1 comment... Ctrl-X is shortcut for edit command "Cut" (along with Ctrl-C & Ctrl-V). You have editable fields in frame. I used Ctrl-Q (quit) instead.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;

import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.ActionMapUIResource;

import java.net.*;

public class HotKeys extends JFrame {
public static void main(String arg[]) {
    JLabel Name = new JLabel("Name");
    JTextField tf1 = new JTextField(20);
    Name.setLabelFor(tf1);
    Name.setDisplayedMnemonic('N');

    JLabel Regno = new JLabel("RegNO");
    JTextField tf2 = new JTextField(20);
    Regno.setLabelFor(tf2);
    Regno.setDisplayedMnemonic('R');

    JLabel Mark1 = new JLabel("Mark1");
    JTextField tf3 = new JTextField(20);
    Mark1.setLabelFor(tf3);
    Mark1.setDisplayedMnemonic('1');

    JLabel Mark2 = new JLabel("Mark2");
    JTextField tf4 = new JTextField(20);
    Mark2.setLabelFor(tf4);
    Mark2.setDisplayedMnemonic('2');

    JButton b1 = new JButton("Save");
    JButton b2 = new JButton("eXit");

    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    JPanel p = new JPanel();

    p.add(Name);
    p.add(tf1);
    p.add(Regno);
    p.add(tf2);
    p.add(Mark1);
    p.add(tf3);
    p.add(Mark2);
    p.add(tf4);
    p.add(b1);
    p.add(b2);

    // *****************************************************
    ActionMap actionMap = new ActionMapUIResource();
    actionMap.put("action_save", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Save action performed.");
        }
    });
    actionMap.put("action_exit", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("Exit action performed.");
        }
    });

    InputMap keyMap = new ComponentInputMap(p);
    keyMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_S,
            java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK), "action_save");
    keyMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Q,
            java.awt.Event.CTRL_MASK), "action_exit");
    SwingUtilities.replaceUIActionMap(p, actionMap);
    SwingUtilities.replaceUIInputMap(p, JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW,
            keyMap);
    // *****************************************************

    f.add(p);
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.pack();
}
}
```

Comment: no - you _never_ (read: except when you really intent to :-) want to use those replaceXX methods. a) you install those new maps - at least the ActionMap - for _all_ instances of JPanel b) doesn't survive a switch of LAF

Comment: slight correction to my last comment: b) is incorrect because XXPanelUI doesn't install any maps at all

Comment: I've tried Ctrl-X (java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_X) - it was ignored by GUI. After this i changed to java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_Q. Perhaps I was wrong in attempt to descibe why, but fact is that java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_X didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I provide this as much for me as a learning experience as for anyone else. I've always had difficulty applying code snippets for key binding that I've found in the past and I hope my explanation and code will be clear. Thanks to @kleopatra for her code snippet, on which I base my code below.

(I'm using CAPITAL LETTERS where I should NOT in order to more clearly show what MUST MATCH.)

The code links the `Ctrl-Shift-U` keystroke to the code in `actionPerformed` for `MYACTION` via the matching strings in `getInputMap` and `getActionMap`.

The three instances of `MYACTION` below must match, as must the four instances of `MYACTIONBUTTON`, as must the two instances of the string `MAKE_THESE_MATCH`. Call them what you will; just make them match.

The button `MYACTIONBUTTON` must have `MYACTION` as the argument to the `JButton` defining it AND must have `getInputMap` and `getActionMap` applied to it.

```
private static JButton MYACTIONBUTTON;
private static JFrame frame;
private static JPanel panel;
```

...

```
Action MYACTION = new AbstractAction()
{

  @Override
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
  {
      // put action code here
  }
};

MYACTIONBUTTON = new JButton(MYACTION);

MYACTIONBUTTON.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)

                           .put(getKeyStroke(VK_U, CTRL_DOWN_MASK | SHIFT_DOWN_MASK),

                                  "MAKE_THESE_MATCH"); 

MYACTIONBUTTON.getActionMap().put("MAKE_THESE_MATCH",        MYACTION);

panel.add(MYACTIONBUTTON);

frame.add(panel);
```