# Triggering a JButton with a specific key

Tags: java, action, key-bindings

I'm attempting to work with Java key bindings for the first time and am having trouble understanding how bindings connect to actions. My goal is to use an InputMap to connect a specific key to a JButton so that the button performs its normal function when that key is pressed. I am not using a Key Listener because I want this event to trigger when the window is focused, not just the button itself. (a `WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW` binding)

If I have this simple button:

```
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;


public class basicButton extends JFrame{
public static void main (String args[]) {

        JButton button = new JButton("Button1");
            button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    System.out.println("Button pressed");
                }
            });

        basicButton t = new basicButton();
        t.add(button);
        t.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        t.setSize(100, 100);
        t.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

How do I make it print "button pressed" when the Insert key is pressed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588145/create-hot-keys-for-jbutton-in-java-using-swing Duplicate?

Answer (score 0):

(sorry cannot comment yet)

so you have to listen mouse and keyboard.

basically, 
when the mouse over, listen for a key press.
when the mouse out, ignore a key press.

Use "KeyEvent" instead. 
tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html